# Reverse to print a string word by word?

Tags: c, string, reverse

example:

- Hello World
- olleH dlroW

i tried to use together strtok and strrev functions but i couldn't.
i can reverse a string but i can't word by word as in the example above.

Comment: I tried to use strtok and strrev. but I could not. @Michael Petrotta

Comment: Describe what you tried, with code, and what problems you encountered. The more detail the better.

Answer (score 1):

First, start from beginning (mark it) and go forward. When you hit a whitespace, or end of string, mark your position and do the following:

Go backwards (from your current position to your last mark), making sure you don't hit an invalid memory location when dereferencing pointers and print every character on your way there. Go to step 1, setting a new beginning mark where you left off.

Continue previous steps until you've read your string entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the strtok() function from string.h and just print each token from the end to the beginning. If it seems difficult dry breaking the problem in smaller ones. For instance try and make a program that prints a string in reverse.

If you provide some code we would be able to give you better help.

Comment: I thought to use together strrok and strrev functions but i couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what programming language you using.
If using c# then

1. you can split your string into array of strings using string.split() method with whitespace as your deliminator.
2. Reverse each string in an array
3. Concat all the strings of the array to create the reverse of the original.

Comment: I've tagged the question with c.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're already familiar with setting up `strtok`, if not just ask. Basically you'll want to set `strtok` up, then while it doesn't return NULL, you'll have to pass the pointer it returns to `strrev`, then replace the terminating NULL placed by `strtok` with a space.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all of you. I think I found the answer, this code worked.

```
int main ()
    {
        char string[100];
        char*word;

        printf("your sentence: \n");
        gets(string);
        word=strtok(string," ");

        while(word!=NULL){
        strrev(word);
        printf("%s ",word);
        word=strtok(NULL," ");
        } 
        getch();
      return 0;
    }
```